# "This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes...."

Tags: ios, xcode

I don't understand where it can come from... I don't know if it is linked, but I pass an "activityIndicator" and a "statusLabel" from a view to another, is it the problem ?

```
    This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
     Stack:(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x246cf883 <redacted> + 150
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35dcedff objc_exception_throw + 38
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x246cf7b1 <redacted> + 0
        3   Foundation                          0x2556be63 <redacted> + 170
        4   Foundation                          0x25411ba7 <redacted> + 38
        5   UIKit                               0x288e3aa9 <redacted> + 52
        6   UIKit                               0x288e4487 <redacted> + 222
        7   UIKit                               0x28fbcfa5 <redacted> + 288
        8   UIKit                               0x28ad5fa9 <redacted> + 148
        9   UIKit                               0x287dd6bb <redacted> + 694
        10  QuartzCore                          0x280a967d <redacted> + 128
        11  QuartzCore                          0x280a4d79 <redacted> + 352
        12  QuartzCore                          0x280a4c09 <redacted> + 16
        13  QuartzCore                          0x280a4129 <redacted> + 368
        14  QuartzCore                          0x280a3deb <redacted> + 590
        15  QuartzCore                          0x280d1777 <redacted> + 310
        16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36666921 <redacted> + 508
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36666523 <redacted> + 86
        18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667499 pthread_exit + 28
        19  Foundation                          0x253e9787 <redacted> + 10
        20  Foundation                          0x254a481f <redacted> + 1178
        21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667c93 <redacted> + 138
        22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667c07 _pthread_start + 110
        23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36665a24 thread_start + 8
    )
    2015-12-02 11:35:03.138 QRCodeReader[735:277009] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
     Stack:(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x246cf883 <redacted> + 150
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35dcedff objc_exception_throw + 38
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x246cf7b1 <redacted> + 0
        3   Foundation                          0x2556be63 <redacted> + 170
        4   Foundation                          0x25411ba7 <redacted> + 38
        5   UIKit                               0x288e3aa9 <redacted> + 52
        6   UIKit                               0x28fbc9d9 <redacted> + 132
        7   UIKit                               0x288e478b <redacted> + 86
        8   Foundation                          0x25411c81 <redacted> + 256
        9   UIKit                               0x288e3aa9 <redacted> + 52
        10  UIKit                               0x288e4487 <redacted> + 222
        11  UIKit                               0x28fbcfa5 <redacted> + 288
        12  UIKit                               0x28ad5fa9 <redacted> + 148
        13  UIKit                               0x287dd6bb <redacted> + 694
        14  QuartzCore                          0x280a967d <redacted> + 128
        15  QuartzCore                          0x280a4d79 <redacted> + 352
        16  QuartzCore                          0x280a4c09 <redacted> + 16
        17  QuartzCore                          0x280a4129 <redacted> + 368
        18  QuartzCore                          0x280a3deb <redacted> + 590
        19  QuartzCore                          0x280d1777 <redacted> + 310
        20  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36666921 <redacted> + 508
        21  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36666523 <redacted> + 86
        22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667499 pthread_exit + 28
        23  Foundation                          0x253e9787 <redacted> + 10
        24  Foundation                          0x254a481f <redacted> + 1178
        25  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667c93 <redacted> + 138
        26  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667c07 _pthread_start + 110
        27  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36665a24 thread_start + 8
    )
    2015-12-02 11:35:03.150 QRCodeReader[735:277009] This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.
     Stack:(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x246cf883 <redacted> + 150
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x35dcedff objc_exception_throw + 38
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x246cf7b1 <redacted> + 0
        3   Foundation                          0x2556be63 <redacted> + 170
        4   Foundation                          0x254160ef <redacted> + 38
        5   Foundation                          0x25411ceb <redacted> + 362
        6   UIKit                               0x288e3aa9 <redacted> + 52
        7   UIKit                               0x288e4487 <redacted> + 222
        8   UIKit                               0x28fbcfa5 <redacted> + 288
        9   UIKit                               0x28ad5fa9 <redacted> + 148
        10  UIKit                               0x287dd6bb <redacted> + 694
        11  QuartzCore                          0x280a967d <redacted> + 128
        12  QuartzCore                          0x280a4d79 <redacted> + 352
        13  QuartzCore                          0x280a4c09 <redacted> + 16
        14  QuartzCore                          0x280a4129 <redacted> + 368
        15  QuartzCore                          0x280a3deb <redacted> + 590
        16  QuartzCore                          0x280d1777 <redacted> + 310
        17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36666921 <redacted> + 508
        18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36666523 <redacted> + 86
        19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667499 pthread_exit + 28
        20  Foundation                          0x253e9787 <redacted> + 10
        21  Foundation                          0x254a481f <redacted> + 1178
        22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667c93 <redacted> + 138
        23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36667c07 _pthread_start + 110
        24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x36665a24 thread_start + 8
    )
```

To be more precise : 
In the first class, I pass the activityIndicator and the statusLabel :

```
    [DataManagementObj WebServiceLogin: activityIndicator withLabel:statusLabel];
```

In the second class where it is waiting for the response server finishing :

```
    -(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
    {
        NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading");

        // OTHER CODE HERE TO HANDLE THE RESPONSE....
        NSLog(@"connection url : %@", connection.currentRequest.URL);
        NSLog(@"connection url : %@", [NSURL URLWithString:get_device_list_from_retailer_WS]);

        if ([connection.currentRequest.URL isEqual: [NSURL URLWithString:login_WS]])
        {
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            NSLog(@"%@",[response objectForKey:@"key"]);
            int key = [[response objectForKey:@"key"] integerValue];
            [self updateUser:key];
     ======>[self stopSynchronizationAnimation];
        }
        else if ([connection.currentRequest.URL isEqual: [NSURL URLWithString:get_retailer_list_from_wholesaler_WS]])
        {
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            [self updateRetailerList: response];
     ======>[self stopSynchronizationAnimation];
        }
        else if ([connection.currentRequest.URL isEqual: [NSURL URLWithString:get_device_list_from_wholesaler_WS]])
        {
            NSError* error;
            NSDictionary* response = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:receivedData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
            [self update3TablesList: response];
     ======>[self stopSynchronizationAnimation];

    etc...
```

If someone have any idea ? Many thanks.

Comment: You are manipulating the UI elements from background thread. You should only manipulate UI element from main thread.

Comment: You need to look at where you are performing asynchronous operations - where you get callbacks; If these are on a background thread then you need to dispatch UI updates on the main queue

Comment: Do you have any closure where you try to change the layout of a view or just set text in a UIlabel?

Comment: Concerning your comments, I did a precision in the Question

Comment: @Claudio I think your stop stopSynchronizationAnimation function has some animations which are running in a background thread(asynchronously).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to switch to the main thread in order to call user interface code. The easiest way to do that is`dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()`.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(){
    [self stopSynchronizationAnimation];
    // reload data on collection view or table view
});
```